# JSON Array changes when sent to Express Server from iOS

Tags: ios, json, node.js, express, afnetworking-3

I am using AFNetworking 3.0 to send data to an Express Server. When I post data which is as below:

```
{
    Services =     (
                {
            id = 2;
            name = "Android Development";
        },
                {
            id = 3;
            name = "iOS Development";
        }
    );
}
```

and in json it would be:

```
{ "Services": [{"id": 2, "name": "Android Development"}, {"id": 3, "name": "iOS Development"}] }
```

but when it arrives on the node server it changes to this:

```
{ "Services": [{"id": [2, 3], "name": ["Android Development", "iOS Development"]}] }
```

Everything works fine if the Array has just one element but as soon as we add multiple entries it changes to this.

On the express server we have this code in place for the parsers:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "50mb", parameterLimit: 50000 }));
```

Note that for Android and Web App everything is working fine, the problem is on iOS only.

This is the code from iOS App:

```
[self.requestSerializer setValue:[[DataModelSingleton sharedInstance] userDO].serverAuthToken   forHTTPHeaderField:@"token"];


        NSDictionary *parameters = tagsData[@"tagsDict"];
        NSString *sessionId = tagsData[@"sessionId"];

        NSMutableString *endpointURL = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", AppKeysAndConstants.baseURL, @"sessions/"];
        NSString *endpointAndToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", endpointURL, sessionId];
[self PUT:endpointAndToken
          parameters:parameters
             success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * Nonnull task, id  Nullable responseObject) {
                 NSLog(@"succes response update serviceTags%@", responseObject);
                 /* code = 200;
                  data = "Entry has been updated.";
                  status = 1;*/
                 resultBlock(@{
                               @"code": responseObject[@"code"],
                               @"message": responseObject[@"status"],
                               @"data": responseObject[@"data"]});

             } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  _Nullable task, NSError  _Nonnull error) {
                 NSLog(@"failure response update serviceTags");
                 NSData *errorData = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey];
                 NSDictionary *serializedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: errorData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

                 if ([serializedData valueForKey:@"code"] != nil) {
                     resultBlock(@{
                                   @"code": serializedData[@"code"],
                                   @"message": serializedData[@"data"]});
                 }else{
                     resultBlock(@{
                                   @"code": @"401",
                                   @"message": @"Error 55"});
                 }
             }]
```

Comment: What does the actual PUT request body look like?

Comment: `{
    Services =     (
                {
            id = 2;
            name = "Android Development";
        },
                {
            id = 3;
            name = "iOS Development";
        }
    );
}`

These are the parameters, or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean, what does the body of the PUT request look like when it gets sent to your server. Remove the `bodyParser` lines and then use something like `app.put(function (req, res) { req.pipe(process.stdout); res.end() }` and then tell me what gets printed to your console.

Comment: { Services: [ { id: ["2", "3"], name: ["Android Development", "iOS Development"] } ],
  id: '1559',
  type: 2 }

Comment: Proper JSON would have double quotes around all the keys and string values. I'm guessing that you're not serializing the `parameters` correctly. Shouldn't you be doing something like `NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:parameters options:kNilOptions error:&error]` and then send that? Also, make sure that you're setting the `Content-Type: application/json` request header.

Comment: the json is changing only when there are more than one elements in the array, for 1 element the code works fine.